# I want my background in 3 pieces to be stationary in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am developing asp.net webforms with a background that is made up of 3 images; top, left and right. The 3 pieces are cropped from a full image to accomodate for content body of 770px width in the middle. At present, these 3 images moves with the body content as I scroll down or up. I would like the background to remain stationary when I scroll the page. I use this code in plain html which works for a single full background image:

```
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
       <title>Layout Example</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Layout Example_files/style.css">
       <style type="text/css">
          body{
            background:  url( "images/SoapBubbles.jpg" ) no-repeat fixed top center;
        }
       </style>
    </head>
```

How do I do this in asp.net even for just one single image for the whole background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a separate div and use fixed positioning on it. Example

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Layout Example</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Layout Example_files/style.css">
   <style type="text/css">
      .fixed-background{
        background:  url( "images/SoapBubbles.jpg" ) no-repeat fixed top center;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:-1;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="fixed-background"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```